# what dose @param notation in javaScript

Tags: javascript

```
/**
 * Create mulit signature wallet function
 * @param account {String} account name
 * @returns {String} Return multisig wallet address
 */
const createMultiSigWallet = async(account) => {
    if (!account) throw new Error('Account name is required.');
    let keys = [];
    await keys.push(await creat`enter code here`eWallet());
    await keys.push(await createWallet());
    //keys.toString();`enter code here`
    //console.log(client.execute('addmultisigaddress', [2, keys, account]));
    return client.execute('addmultisigaddress', [2, keys, account]);
};
```

it is function of node.js what does mean @param in javascript

Comment: It doesn’t mean anything in JavaScript - because it is part of a _comment_. These _annotations_ are used by software that automatically creates documentation based on code.

Comment: Ref: [LINK](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's a part of the comments of the code. 
The @param indicates the inputs for the function, the @returns indicates what will be returned from the function.

These things have no impact on the code itself, only on the comments and whatever external software that uses them to generate documentation

Answer (score 0):

From [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html):

> The `@param` tag provides the name, type, and description of a
>   function parameter.